# Can I use Z-push in my web-application?

Tags: php, activesync

I have a website that acts as a calendar manager amongst other things.

Now, some of the users need to sync some calendar events to an MDaemon server, while others need Exchange Online sync.

I already have developed an EWS and a CalDav connector, but non of these seem to work with MDaemon.

Do you know if there's some kind of library or protocol I can use for this?

Is ActiveSync an option?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; it seems like you want to use an ActiveSync CLIENT? Z-Push is an ActiveSync Server Implementation. You said you'd like to Sync your calendars to multiple servers, thus your web app would need an EAS Client, right?

Comment: Yes, actually I'd need some sort of a client for to sync multiple calendars (one per user, at most). Sorry for my minimal english

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any such PHP Library or Solution, all the EAS Solutions for PHP are Servers, not Clients :/

Comment: Darn :( looks like I'll need to develop a specific connector for the MDaemon platform then. I am wondering how on earth is my smartphone able to do it...